# Issues with Symfony 4.3.1 and FosUserBundle 2.1.2

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

For a new project, I use Symfony 4.3 and FosUserBundle 2.1. I installed with success this bundle but when I try to use it, I've got somes issues.

When I try to access on login page (http://127.0.0.1:8000/login), it works well. But, on register page I've got some errors:

`Property "superAdmin" does not exist in class "App\Entity\User"`

I try to add the properties `superAdmin` and `group` in my User entity (I don't know if it's a good idea). The page is displayed correctly. Now, when I try to submit register form, 4 errors appear (all fields are filled):

- This value should not be null. => "data.password"
- This value should not be null. => "data.superAdmin"
- This value should not be null. => "data.groups"
- This value should not be null. => "data.group"

Is FosUserBundle compatible with Symfony 4.3? How to solve these problems? Are there alternatives?

Comment: Does your User Entity extend `BaseUser` of fosuserbundle?

Comment: Can you share a reproducable example triggering that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution : 
==> you must add $group and $superAdmin in your entity User, so you can just set $group to nullable=true, and $superAdmin is boolean you can set it to true or false. **NB: you must rename the column group because this group is reserved word in mysql** , I set these in constructor so you can set these in custom form to like :

```html
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace App\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $prenom;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $superAdmin;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="giroupy", type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $group;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->superAdmin = false;
        $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
        // your own logic
        if (empty($this->registerDate)) {
            $this->registerDate = new \DateTime();
        }
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getPrenom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prenom;
    }

    public function setPrenom(string $prenom): self
    {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGroup(): ?string
    {
        return $this->group;
    }

    public function setGroup(?string $group): self
    {
        $this->group = $group;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSuperAdmin(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->superAdmin;
    }


    public function setSuperAdmin($superAdmin): self
    {
        $this->superAdmin = $superAdmin;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

so after to set password you must hook formEvent  for event SUBMIT to get the entity User like :

```html
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Form/RegistrationType.php

namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    private $userPassWordInterface;
    public function __construct(
        UserPasswordEncoderInterface $userPassWordInterface
    )
    {
        $this->userPassWordInterface = $userPassWordInterface;
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('prenom')
        ->addEventListener(
                FormEvents::SUBMIT,
                [$this, 'onSubmit']
            )
        ;
    }

    public function onSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (!$user) {
            return;
        }
        $passWord = $this->userPassWordInterface->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
        $user->setPassWord($passWord);

        // checks whether the user has chosen to display their email or not.
        // If the data was submitted previously, the additional value that
        // is included in the request variables needs to be removed.

    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }

    // For Symfony 2.x
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }
}
```

and in security like :

```html
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers

    encoders:
        App\Entity\User: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

so after set the form login in your package : config/packages/fos_user.yaml

```html
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: App\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: App\Form\RegistrationType
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
```

and don't forget to load routes in : config/routes/fos_user.yaml

```html
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is much simpler. FOSUserBundle is still compatible with Symfony 4.3, it's just doesn't work with 4.3 validator component automatic validation settings, which is turned on by default:

```
framework:
    validation:
        email_validation_mode: html5

        # Enables validator auto-mapping support.
        # For instance, basic validation constraints will be inferred from Doctrine's metadata.
        auto_mapping:       # <----- REMOVE THIS THIS
            App\Entity\: [] # <-------- AND THIS
```

It solved the problem in my case, but it also means that you need to set validation rules manually.

Comment: Will this cause the entity not to be validated at all?  If so, I think you should include a warning along with your suggestion, just in case any newbies reading this don't realise.

Comment: @TobyG added a warning, maybe it will help someone